# Offline address fetching

Tags: ios, swift

I need to fetch the user current location in offline, I got user latitude and longitude in offline, But I need corresponding address of it, I tried using geocode but it worked only in online, Can another possible way to get address while user in offline .

Answer (score 0):

Fetching latitude and longitude uses your GPS so, you don't need internet connection, but to reverse geocode it, you will be needing internet connection to fetch the address from apple's database.. same goes for google maps.

There are however lightweight libraries available, which might reverse geocode the address for you to country level, but if you want exact address up to some administrative level addresses, you definitely need internet connection.